# How to call Strace native library in Android application?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, strace, android-native-library

I am developing an android application where I imported [Strace for Android](https://github.com/android/platform_external_strace) which contains .c files, shown in the image below.

[image: .c files in cpp folder]

All the .c files are added automatically in the `cpp` folder when i gave the path of `Android.mk` file. the Android.mk file is given in [this link](https://github.com/android/platform_external_strace/blob/master/Android.mk) and `MainActivity.java` is as follows:

[image]

The problem is that when I give the name of starce.c as the native library the application stops unexpectedly. Anyone knows why this is happening?

Thanks in advance